# Does T(n) = 2 · T(2n) + n apply to Master method?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, recurrence-relation, master-theorem

I'm trying to apply the [master method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) to the following recurrence:

$$T(n) = 2 \cdot T(2n)+n.$$

We have $a=2$ and $b=1/2$.

Also,
$f(n)=n$
and
$n^{\log_b a} = n^{\log_{1/2} 2} = n^{-1}$ since $\log_{1/2} 2 = -1$.

So, case 3 applies since $f(n) = \Omega(n^{\log_b a+\epsilon })$ , i.e., $n = \Omega(n^{-1+2})$ for some constant $\epsilon = 2$.

Now we have to check the regularity condition:

For some constant $c<1$, it must hold that $af(n/b) \leq cf(n)$.

That is (substitute $a$ and $b$ in the above regularity condition):

- $2 \cdot 2n \leq c \cdot n$
- $4n \leq c \cdot n$

Which cannot hold for any $c < 1$

Hence, we cannot apply case 3.

**Is the above a correct application of Master theorem for this recurrence? And what would be the solution?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From wikipedia

"Here $n$ is the size of an input problem, $a$ is the number of subproblems in the recursion, and $b$ is the factor by which the subproblem size is reduced in each recursive call $(b>1)$"

---

So no. Master theorem can not be used to solve the given recurrence.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this important condition. So can we have an asymptotic bound on this recurrence? It seems no right?

Comment: Jarvis, just write down T(1) = c. Then write down other values of T(n) from your equation and try to find a pattern. For example T(2), T(4) etc.

Comment: You can reorganize the recurrence so that you have the "larger" (i.e. $T(2n)$) alone on the LHS, and then you get that $T$ indeed is $O(n)$.

Comment: Jarvis, are you just blindly plugging numbers into formulas? You need to actually understand what the given equation means. One look at the formula should make you think “hey, this looks strange…”

Comment: Yes I agree, it looks quite strange! I have these types of questions very often, for instance one time one was asking for Big-O of the following recurrence: $T(n)=n^3 - n^5$ !

Comment: @Jarvis recurrences are not just limited to expressing runtime of problems, they are all over the place, however master theorem deals with the former. Yves' answer shows how you can manipulate the recurrence to get it to work with master theorem.

Comment: @RinkeshP: in fact, this problem is not about a feasible runtime, as the values of $T$ must be negative !

Answer (score 13):

The Master Theorem is not deemed to be used with $b<1$. But you can recast the recurrence as

$$T(2n)=\frac12T(n)-\frac n2$$

or

$$T(n)=\frac12T\left(\frac n2\right)-\frac n4.$$

So yes, the Master Theorem can be used.